# String matching background-color value is not evaluating to true

Tags: jquery, css

I have seen a recent post similar to this however the answers did not work.
I am trying to make a Connect four game and basically my problem is that each time i click a box it changes the color, however if i click a coloured box it also changes that to the next color. I would like each box to stay that color if its is red or yellow.

```
 if ($(this).css('background-color') == $(this).css('background-color', 'silver'))
```

or

```
 if ($(this).css('background-color') != 'red') || (if ($(this).css('background-color')  !='yellow))
```

it just skips over this if statement?

Comment: Well, `'red'` is just one way of saying red. It may be `'#FF0000'` too. Or `'rgb(255, 0, 0)'`. Or `'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'`.

Comment: I think you should change it to work with classes and not color css values. When you change the state of the checkbox then change the class. And your If will check for class names too. It'll be much easier for you.

Comment: In the first `if`, you are comparing `string` and `object`.

Comment: The syntax for the second check is completely off, should be:
`if (($(this).css('background-color') != 'red') || ($(this).css('background-color') != 'yellow') )`

Answer (score 1):

For your first `if` statement, change:

```
if ($(this).css('background-color') == $(this).css('background-color', 'silver'))
```

To:

```
if ($(this).css('background-color') == 'silver')
```

Calling `$(this).css('background-color', 'silver'))` sets the `background-color` of that element to silver and attempts to compare its `background-color` to itself as an object.

Your second `if` statement is badly formed and will not work. Change it to:

```
if ($(this).css('background-color') != 'red' || $(this).css('background-color') !='yellow')
```

Please note, however, that this will **always** be true, as you're asking whether the background isn't red **or** the background isn't yellow. If the background *is* red, the background will not be yellow, and vice versa. Change that `||` to `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method has different outputs in different browsers:

```
$('<div>').css('background-color', 'red').css('background-color');

// Google Chrome
// "red"

// Mozilla Firefox
// "rgb(255, 0, 0)"
```

Another example:

```
$('<div>').css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)').css('background-color');

// Google Chrome
// "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"

// Mozilla Firefox
// "transparent"
```

---

## SOLUTION

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/pHCTh/1/)**</kbd>

Create an object to store all your colors with all possible situations:

```
var colors = {
    'red'  : ['red'  , '#FF0000', '#ff0000', 'rgb(255, 0, 0)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'],
    'green': ['green', '#00ff00', '#00FF00', 'rgb(0, 255, 0)', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)']

    // etc
};
```

Now you can use [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) method for comparing:

### HTML

```
<div id="test1" style="background-color: red;">I am RED</div>
<div id="test2" style="background-color: blue;">I am Blue</div>
```

### JS

```
// you want to see if `elem_color` is `red`
// just like this: elem_color == 'red'

var elem_color = $('#test1').css('background-color');

if ($.inArray(elem_color, colors['red']) > -1) {
    alert('Element is RED');
}

// you want to see if `elem_color` is not `green`
// just like this: elem_color != 'green'

var elem_color = $('#test2').css('background-color');

if (! ($.inArray(elem_color, colors['green']) > -1)) {
    alert('Element is not GREEN');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the #FF0000 or the normal red? If your red is #FF0001, it doesn't recognize it as red.

You need to make your statement exactly the same as the original color, should work!